# How to add additional mesh (clothing) for an already existing and animating humanoid mesh in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender

I have a working animation in Unity. I've made the mesh in Blender. The animation has two simple steps.

A guy stands:

[image]

then he reaches for a point above his head:

[image]

It's working and played perfectly by Unity. 
Sidenote: I'm accomplishing this movement by "Raw Mocap Data" asset and I'm just  doing the regular way: adding an avatar to the scen then make him move by a controller. The guy is an .fbx file exported from Blender.
Nothing special.

But here is my problem: I'm trying to add a priesthood to the guy's animation unsuccessfully.

This is the basic mesh in Blender:

[image]

and here is the mesh with the priesthood:

[image]

Unity successfully plays the animation: the guy raises his hand, however the priesthood's sleeve doesn't animate with the guy's hand simultaniously. The priesthood's sleeve stays in its horizontal starting position and refuses to move a single pixel:

[image]

My question is: how to move the sleeve with the animated hand together? Should I do the job on Blender side? Or should I correct something in Unity?

Comment: You will get better answers in a cg forum, as this is for programming.

Answer (score 2):

> how to move the sleeve with the animated hand together?

I am not a blender guy. I use **Maya** but I will tell you that you **don't animate** cloths. You **simulate** them. You can **attach** the **cloth** to the **body** and **arm** by pinning or any other **Blender** supported method then **animate** only the **hand**. Use Dynamic Follow to then make the cloth follow the hand.There are **scripts** to do this in Maya. **Bake** the **animation** and **transfer** to **Unity**. Most complete tutorials about this topic is either for **Maya** or **3ds Max**. You have have to google a lot to find complete blender **character/cloth** animation, **baking** and **transfer** to **Unity**.

> Should I do the job on Blender side?

Do the animation in **Blender**. **Unity Cloth** is known to slow things down. Unity claims that they fixed it in **5.0** but I don't think so. Just pretend that **Unity Clothing** is doing **Blender Simulation** in real time. It does lots of **calculations** in real time but when you do the animation **Blender**, **Unity** won't have to **perform** those **calculations**. You may not notice it now but when you have **many** 3D objects with HQ Textures in the scene, you will notice it and your game will require a **high end** computer to run **well**.